# Custom decorator in flask not working?

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I have the following code:

```
import datetime
from flask.app import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.debug = True

def track_time_spent(name):
  def decorator(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
      start = datetime.datetime.now()
      ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
      delta = datetime.datetime.now() - start
      print name, "took", delta.total_seconds(), "seconds"
      return ret
    return wrapped
  return decorator

@app.route('/foo')
@track_time_spent('foo')
def foo():
  print "foo"
  return "foo"

@app.route('/bar')
@track_time_spent('bar')
def bar():
  print "bar"
  return "bar"
```

I am unable to get foo to return 'foo':

```
$ curl localhost:8888/foo
bar

(flask window) 
bar
bar took 8.2e-05 seconds
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013 19:21:31] "GET /foo HTTP/1.1" 200 -

$ curl localhost:8888/bar
bar

(flask window)
bar
bar took 3.5e-05 seconds
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013 19:21:35] "GET /bar HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What's going on? Why isn't my decorator working?

**EDIT**

I don't think you guys seem to be able to see the problem.

When I have `@app.route` before `@track_time_spent`, **both** methods return bar. The error here is that calling localhost:8888/foo results in `bar` in both the http response as well as the print function.

Comment: What do you mean by "other window"?

Comment: flask does not use function object you wrote 'directly', instead it stores it into underlying werkzeug bases and calls them upon request.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The other answers seem to be missing that you're getting "bar" as a response from "/foo" when you switch the order of the decorators. You must use `@wraps` here unless you update the `__name__`, `__module__`, and such manually. Flask uses your methods kinda like singletons, and sees your decorator just as the `wrapped()` method, instead of the methods you actually wrapped. Hence, your routes will keep getting overwritten by the last method to use your decorator.

```
import datetime
from functools import wraps

from flask.app import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.debug = True


def track_time_spent(name):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            start = datetime.datetime.now()
            ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
            delta = datetime.datetime.now() - start
            print name, "took", delta.total_seconds(), "seconds"
            return ret
        return wrapped
    return decorator


@app.route('/foo')
@track_time_spent('foo')
def foo():
    print "foo"
    return "foo"


@app.route('/bar')
@track_time_spent('bar')
def bar():
    print "bar"
    return "bar"

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8888)
```

Answer (score 3):

Flask's `route` function is a registering function in the sense you call it for its side effect - it'll register your view function for an endpoint. However, you're registering just the view function, not the *decorated* view function. Simply switch the order of decorators to register the "time-tracked" function.

Also, you can use @app.before_request and @app.teardown_request-registered functions to track time more reliably (taking into account the time it took to render the template and such).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saying your decorator isn't working?

In your second example, the decorator is running, and it's realistic that such a simple function would execute in 0.035 ms (3.5e-05 is a notation that means 3.5 times 10 to the power of -5).

---

For reference, the reason why you needed to reverse the order of the two decorator is because `app.route` registers the function that it is being passed.

Hence you need to pass it the decorated function, hence the order.

Comment: I claim that my decorator isn't working because accessing /foo returns 'bar'