# Decorator doesn't works in flask

Tags: python, flask

I was writing a decorator for flask which checks if user is authenticated:

```py
def not_login_required(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

But when I use it

```py
@not_login_required
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # many code
```

It does nothing

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good description of the problem. What does it do? Does it get an error?

Comment: You might need to put the decorators in the other order. `@app.route()` is what uses the returned value from the function to send back to the client.

Comment: @Barmar, it does nothing

Comment: You should change the order of decorators, because you want flask to apply decorated function on http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited decorator like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096211/custom-decorator-in-flask-not-working)

```py
from functools import wraps

# ...

def not_login_required(name):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect('/')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

And I changed order:

```py
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@not_login_required('login')
def login():
    # many code
```

Answer (score 1):

The `route()` decorator *must* be the outermost decorator, according to the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/viewdecorators/):

> To use the decorator, apply it as innermost decorator to a view function. **When applying further decorators, always remember that the `route()` decorator is the outermost.**

So your code should look like this:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@not_login_required
def login():
    # many code
```